# How can I include survey weights in a poisson pint process model fitted to a logistic regression quadrature scheme?

Tags: spatial, spatstat

Is it possible to include weights in a poisson point process model fitted to a logistic regression quadrature scheme? My data is a stratified sample and I would like to account for this sampling strategy in order to have valid population level predictions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696016/converting-point-process-model-intensity-predictions-to-probabilities-at-specifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few lines to elaborate on the answer by @adrian-baddeley.

If you have the setup of your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58696016/3341769) and we imagine you have the weights and two covariates in a `data.frame` in the same order as the points of your `quadscheme`:

```
library(spatstat)
X <- split(chorley)$larynx
D <- split(chorley)$lung
Q <- quadscheme.logi(X,D)
covar <- data.frame(weights = runif(npoints(chorley)),
                    covar1 = rnorm(npoints(chorley)),
                    covar2 = rnorm(npoints(chorley)))
fit <- ppm(Q ~ offset(log(weights)) + covar1 + covar2, data = covar)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about the model-fitting function `ppm` in the R package `spatstat`.

Yes, you can include survey weights. The easiest way is to create a covariate `surveyweight`, which could be a `function(x,y)` or a pixel image or a column of data associated with your quadrature scheme. Then when fitting the model using `ppm`, add the model term `+offset(log(surveyweight))`.

The result of `ppm` will be a fitted model that describes the *observed* point pattern. You can do prediction, simulation etc from this model, but be aware that these will be predictions or simulations of the observed point process including the effect of non-constant survey effort.

To get a prediction or simulation of the original point process (i.e. after removing the effect of non-constant survey effort) you need to replace the original covariate `surveyweight` by another covariate that is constant and equal to 1, then pass this to `predict.ppm` in the argument `newdata`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Sorry - I am not entirely clear how to add `surveyweight`  (in my case as column of data) to the quadrature scheme.  I calculated the quadrature scheme by first splitting my `ppp` by positive/negative outcome of a diagnostic test. Each point (positive or negative) has a weight associated with it.  How do can I then link this to the quadrature scheme?